# Creating a content security policy for embedded Google Maps iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I've created a React component for an embedded Google Maps iframe which works as intended. However, the browser console repeatedly warns me about the content security policy:

[image]

I went looking for solutions, but I only found answers related to the API. The concepts of content security policy and `manifest.json` is new to me and something I'll look into moving forwards, but for now I only need help setting up the manifest.

#### Manifest

```
"permissions": [
  "https://www.google.com/maps/*"
],
"content_security_policy": ""
```

#### Component

```js
import React from "react";

export default function GoogleMap(props: {
    title: string,
    src: string,
    width?: string,
    height?: string
}) {
    return (
        <iframe
            title={ props.title }
            src={ props.src }
            width={ props.width || "100%"}
            height={ props.height || "450"}
            loading="lazy"
        ></iframe>
    )
}
```

#### Component call

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Jumbotron from './components/Jumbotron';
import GoogleMap from './components/GoogleMap';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col">
          <Jumbotron>
            <h1>Hello World!</h1>
            <p>Something, something</p>
          </Jumbotron>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="row">
        <div className="col">
          <GoogleMap
            title="Map of Mobit Stakkevollvegen"
            src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d490.15681762061814!2d18.969382885920925!3d69.66688347864422!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x45c4c45ca1720dbb%3A0x48debf799412e7a8!2sMobit%20Stakkevollvegen!5e0!3m2!1sno!2sno!4v1624610965243!5m2!1sno!2sno"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

What do I put into the `manifest.json` in order to remove the browser console warnings in a secure manner?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if these warnings are exclusive to Firefox, but [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/fpptyj/firefox_content_security_policy_console_output/) seems to say that these warnings are caused by something on Google's end. Therefore, although you should implement a CSP to secure your app, I do not think doing so will remove the warnings.

Comment: Do you have any good resources for learning about CSP?

Comment: @CasperTollefsen The [MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) should be a good place to start.